# Failed: cannot do a full restore on a sharded system - remove the 'config' directory from the dump directory first

Tags: mongodb, gzip, mongorestore

I'm restoring my mongodb on to the sharded cluster and got the following error, Do I need to remove the config info from dumpfile ?

```
2020-06-18T07:20:38.764+0000    preparing collections to restore from
2020-06-18T07:20:38.765+0000    Failed: cannot do a full restore on a sharded system - remove the 'config' directory from the dump directory first
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The config database contains the names of the shards, and metadata about the sharded collections, such as which shard owns which chunks of data.
Copying that database between clusters via mongorestore has a very small probability of it actually containing correct data.
If that were permitted, the most likely result would be the data for all collections in the cluster will not actually be stored where the config database indicates for some portion of the data.

The result would be that chunks of data, possibly entire collections or database, would appear to be missing.

The config database will be created automatically when you enable sharding, and updated internally as necessary when data is moved between shards.

Removing the config directory from the dump will prevent this database being restored, allowing the one created by the current cluster to remain correct.